# Covering Spaces in Representation Theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

I'm reading the paper "Covering Spaces in Representation Theory" of K. Bogartz and P. Gabriel.

Now I'm in section 2, proposition 2.3, on the first three lines concludes that the functor $l \mapsto Hom_{\Lambda}(-,l)$ yields an equivalence $mod \ \Lambda \cong proj \ (ind \ \Lambda)$.

Let $F : mod \ \Lambda \to proj \ (ind \ \Lambda)  $ be the above functor. We are going to give a pseudo-inverse, say $G$. If $g: (ind\ \Lambda)^{op} \to Mod \ k$ is an object of $proj \ (ind \ \Lambda)$, we define a functor $G(g): \Lambda^{op} \to Mod \ k$, by $G(g)(X)=g(Hom_\Lambda (-,X))$. It is clear that this functors is well-defined, and then:

$$
    G \circ F (X) = G\Big(Hom_{\Lambda}(-,X)\Big): \Lambda^{op} \to Mod\ k
$$

is given by $Y \mapsto Hom\Big(Hom_{\Lambda}(-,Y),X\Big)$, and by Yoneda's lemma we get $G \circ F \cong 1_{mod \ \Lambda}$.

For the other composition we have:

$$
   F\circ G (X) = Hom_{\Lambda}(-,G(X))
$$

That sends a module $Y : \Lambda^{op} \to Mod \ k$ to the vector space $Hom_\Lambda (Y,G(X))$.

The thing is, I don't see how $$F \circ G \cong 1_{proj (ind \Lambda)} $$

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is $M$?  What is $ind$ and $proj$ and $mod$?

Comment: The full detail of this is in Assem-Simson-Skowronski's book IV.6.1 - IV.6.5.  The main difficulty is to show that any projective object is of this form (which means the functor is dense); fully faithfulness of the functor is easy to see from Yoneda lemma.  Note: a functor is fully faithful dense iff it gives an equivalence of categories.

Comment: @Aaron: I don't see how Assem-Simson-Skowronski's book give the details of this proof.